# Merging bag-of-words scikits classifier with arbitrary numeric fields

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

How would you merge a scikits-learn [classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) that operates over a bag-of-words with one that operates on arbitrary numeric fields?

I know that these are basically the same thing behind-the-scenes, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this via the existing library methods. For example, my bag-of-words classifier uses the pipeline:

```
classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', HashingVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,4), non_negative=True)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())),
])
classifier.fit(['some random text','some other text', ...], [CLS_A, CLS_B, ...])
```

Whereas my other usage is like:

```
classifier = LinearSVC()
classifier.fit([1.23, 4.23, ...], [CLS_A, CLS_B, ...])
```

How would I construct a LinearSVC classifier that could be trained using both sets of data simeltaneously? e.g.

```
classifier = ?
classifier.fit([('some random text',1.23),('some other text',4.23), ...], [CLS_A, CLS_B, ...])
```

Answer (score 6):

The easy way:

```
import scipy.sparse

tfidf = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', HashingVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,4), non_negative=True)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
])
X_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(texts)

X_other = load_your_other_features()

X = scipy.sparse.hstack([X_tfidf, X_other])

clf = LinearSVC().fit(X, y)
```

The principled solution, which allows you to keep everything in one `Pipeline`, would be to wrap hashing, tf-idf and your other feature extraction method in a few simple transformer objects and put these in a `FeatureUnion`, but it's hard to tell what the code would look like from the information you've given.

(P.S. As I keep saying on SO, on the mailing list and elsewhere, `OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())` is useless. `LinearSVC` does OvR out of the box, so this is just a slower way of fitting an OvR SVM.)

Comment: If `OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())` is useless then why do the official docs use it everywhere? e.g. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

Comment: @Cerin: that's the one and only place where the docs use this idiom, and it shows how to use `OneVsRestClassifier`, not `LinearSVC`. I'll try and change it to something more useful for the next release.